# stop setTimeout after redirect in controller

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem in my ajax call it will continue to call my controller.

**AJAX function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var stopTime =0;
 var scoreCheck =  function ()
    {
      $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkScore'?>",
      success:function(output){
        if(output){
          $('#maincontent1').html(output);
          clearTimeout(stopTime);
            }
        else{
          stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck, 1000);   
            }
    }
  });
}
stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck,3000);
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkScore(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $battleID = $this->lawmodel->getBattle($id);
    foreach($battleID as $row){
        $Rscore = $row->requestedScore;
        $Cscore = $row->challengerScore;
        if($Cscore=="1"){
                redirect('main/secondRound');
            }
        else if($Rscore == '1'){
            redirect('main/secondRound');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **secondRound function**

```
public function secondRound(){
    $category = 'medium';
    $data['results'] = $this->lawmodel->roundTwoQuestion($category);
    $data['content'] = 'battlePage';
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/template2',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/restricted');
    }
}
```

My problem is how can i stop ajax call after the first redirect..since i use setTimeout to always check if there is a change in database. If there is a change in my database it will redirect to another controller. In my model *roundTwoQuestion()* it will query a random data in the database with limit to 1.

In my view..it will continue to redirect/refresh with a random data from my roundTwoQuestion.

PLease help! Im a newbie in ajax. :(

Comment: I am so confused why you are php echoing a URL like that.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov i forgot to clear that...
now edited..im sorry..:(

Comment: @JasonSperske its still work.. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest that it was the source of your problem, it's just that `url: "http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkScore",` would also work and be cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller function is called "CheckScore", so return a check status and test it in the success AJAX callback, then call another function (or redirect with javascript, ...) to redirect if the status is true :

**AJAX function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var stopTime =0;
 var scoreCheck =  function ()
    {
      $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkScore'?>",
      success:function(output){
        if(output === "OK"){
          clearTimeout(stopTime);

          //Ok, now you can redirect using the way you want
        }
        else{
          //Check return a false status, so continue to execute this function
          stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck, 1000);   
        }
    }
  });
}
stopTime = setTimeout(scoreCheck,3000);
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkScore(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $battleID = $this->lawmodel->getBattle($id);

    //Do your check here according to your DB result
    echo ($status) ?"OK" : "KO"; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..but i dont understand your code in controller..xD

Comment: Hard to understand completely the problem without all the project, but the idea is to separate the tasks. 1 controller function to return a check status, another to redirect and return the new render of the view, ...

Comment: anyway thanks...with just your idea..i was able to make it..:)) thanks again..^_^